# Python Two Identical Strings are viewed as Different

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I have two strings that by all indication look identical:

```
x1 = 'N C Soft - NCSOFT_Guild Wars 2 December 2013 :: BNLX_AD_Parallax_160x600'
x2 = 'N C Soft - NCSOFT_Guild Wars 2 December 2013 :: BNLX_CT_Parallax_160X600'
```

However, checking for equality shows they are not.

```
In [312]: if x1 != x2:
   .....:     print 'yep'
   .....:
yep
```

I also tried copying both strings out of command prompt and them pasting them back in as a new variables but they are still not equal. I'm 80% sure it's because they're encoded in a weird way, with some odd characters inserted that I can't see, but using type() both just show up as string.

Is there any way I can see the "real" string? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Comments aren't working too well in terms of skipping a space but the repr() look identical as well

Answer (score 23, accepted):

They are not the same; using [`difflib.ndiff()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#difflib.ndiff) shows how these two values differ very clearly:

```
>>> import difflib
>>> print '\n'.join(difflib.ndiff([x1], [x2]))
- N C Soft - NCSOFT_Guild Wars 2 December 2013 :: BNLX_AD_Parallax_160x600
?                                                      ^^             ^

+ N C Soft - NCSOFT_Guild Wars 2 December 2013 :: BNLX_CT_Parallax_160X600
?                                                      ^^             ^
```

In general, when in doubt use [`repr()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#repr) to look at the representation. Python 2 will use escapes for any non-printable or non-ASCII character in the string, any 'funny' characters will stand out like a sore thumb. In Python 3, use the [`ascii()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ascii) for the same result as `repr()` there is less conservative and Unicode is rife with character combinations that look the same at first glance.

For strings where you still cannot see what changes between the two, the above `difflib` tool can also help point out what exactly changed.

Comment: Ah you're absolutely right -- I provided the wrong example here for sure. But this problem is still real -- let me find a real example.

Comment: @DavidYang: Python doesn't lie to you. Look at the `repr()` output and compare those values; differences like non-breaking whitespace are far more visible.

Comment: @DavidYang: updated to use `difflib.ndiff` to show the precise differences. There is another difference I also missed at first.

Comment: I get that, I don't think python is lying, I just think it's not showing me everything. Finding two strings that appear identical but are not has proven to be quite difficult since I can't exactly search for it. But what I can say is that trying to find common strings between two lists yields nothing, yet I'm 100% positive that the two lists have intersection points since one is created from the other.

Comment: Hmmmm Martijn I believe that second difference is the actual cause of this! Somehow when I created my second list using my first it wasn't case sensitive but now that I'm comparing them, case sensitivity matters!